# Conflicting Conditional Statement with RxJS streams

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I have two tabs on UI and both of them require certain validations.

First Tab - Account Id ( Required)

Second Tab - Account Id + at least 1 selection from list of values. ( Both Required)

Submit button is disabled by default and will be enabled only when the validation criteria is fulfilled.

First Time on first tab - Works as expected. Enabled when account id is filled, disabled when empty

First time on second tab = Works as expected. Enabled when account id is filled and at least one item is selected, disabled when any of the criteria is not fulfilled.

Now, when you go back to first tab - things starts to fail. Primarily because both the streams are active. How can I stop/filter streams and make them work as per the tab selected?

Minimal reproduction here - [Minimal Demo for issue ( app.component.ts)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wsbsg8)

Can someone please take a look and point me in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please also add the expected behavior? The words "validations works on their own" and "they stopped working" don't give much idea of what's the expectation.

Comment: Hi @SiddAjmera - Updated post and there is a reproduction as well. If possible, please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Got it thanks. :) I'm looking into it.

Comment: Hey @SiddAjmera - Any luck? I am almost there. Will post it in a while.

Comment: Not really mate. 

Comment: @SiddAjmera - i got it. Will post it in 10-15 mins

Comment: @SiddAjmera - take a look. Answer posted

Answer (score 1):

So, I was thinking of it in a different way. What I probably end up doing was to finalize which stream will come into picture as soon as the tab on ui is selected. So on every tab change, I will have different stream and it will work as desired.
Demo available here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmkfvp

However, is there a better way to do this if/else via some rxjs operators or this snippet looks ok?

```
 overallValidator$ = this.selectedDomain$.pipe(
    tap(() => console.info('--- Inside tap')),
    switchMap((item) => {
      if (item === this.AML) {
        return this.amlDomainValidator$;
      }
      return this.otherDomainValidator$;
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iif](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/conditional/iif.html)

```
// RxJS v6+
import { iif, of, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const r$ = of('R');
const x$ = of('X');

interval(1000)
  .pipe(mergeMap(v => iif(() => v % 4 === 0, r$, x$)))
  .subscribe(console.log);

// output: R, X, X, X, R, X, X, X, etc...
```